# vsCode java.test.config vmArgs not working

Tags: java, junit, visual-studio-code, vmargs

My project requires the following vmArgs to run :

```
"vmArgs": "-javaagent:lib/aspectjweaver-1.9.5.jar -javaagent:lib/spring-instrument-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar --module-path lib/javafx-sdk-13.0.2/lib --add-modules=javafx.controls"
```

Putting this in the launch.json configuration object makes the project run perfectly.  For unit tests, the same vmArgs should be put into the settings.json's java.test.config object, which I did as you see below :

```
{
    "java.test.config": 
    [
        {
            "name": "testConfig",
            "workingDirectory": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "vmArgs": "-javaagent:lib/aspectjweaver-1.9.5.jar -javaagent:lib/spring-instrument-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar --module-path lib/javafx-sdk-13.0.2/lib --add-modules=javafx.controls"
        }
    ],
    "java.test.defaultConfig": "testConfig"
}
```

This part is not working.  My JUnit tests are not being instrumented correctly.  What am I doing wrong?  The vmArgs line is an exact copy of what I have in launch.json.

Comment: Anyone working on a Java project in vsCode where unit tests require JVM arguments?

Comment: I haven't used JUnit test case within Visual Studio code. However, while comparing your configuration against an example at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-testing, I noticed differences -- (i) JSON structure (you have used array for `java.test.config`) and (ii) arguments are proivided in a comma separated list enclosed in a square bracket. Could this be a reason? What is an exact error message you are getting?

Comment: No error per se but the tests fail because the JVM is not being properly instrumented before the Spring context starts therefore said context can't even initialize.  I saw that page you linked and I think I tried it like that also but I will give it another shot.

Comment: Sadly this does not work either : "vmArgs": ["-javaagent:lib/aspectjweaver-1.9.5.jar","-javaagent:lib/spring-instrument-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar","--module-path lib/javafx-sdk-13.0.2/lib","--add-modules=javafx.controls"]

Answer (score 2):

I think it might be caused by the capitalization. Previously, it's `vmargs` not `vmArgs`. But the extension has changed to support both in this PR: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-test/pull/1080

Do you still have this issue now?