# How to change Java Debug Arguments in vscode launch.json config?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, debugging

I configure `launch.json` to launch Java debugger and working successfully. After a short while, I see error `ERROR: transport error 202: recv error: Connection reset by peer`. I did google it, and it was suggested to change the debug argument from:

`-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=localhost:52252`

to:

`-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=localhost:52252`

The debug arguments above are auto generated by vscode. How I can change it? I didn't find a way to configure such argument. The only option is to configure a task to run the command, and configure a debug option to run the task to launch the debugger and attached to that debugger session.

I am checking if there is a way to change the part to `server=y` as it is much easier.

Comment: Use the `vmArgs` parameter in *launch.json* to add arguments to the jvm.
Or use `"java.debug.settings.vmArgs":` configuration in *settings.json*. Here is the [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging#_launch) explaining it.

Comment: Is there any progress on the problem? If you find the solution, you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also [stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Comment: I accepted the answer but it requires modification. Check the latest comments I added. I can't modify the answer due to limits reached by the site. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack Overflow seems to have these answers. I never tested them myself though.

- [How to set java vmargs in vscode at workspace level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61700234/how-to-set-java-vmargs-in-vscode-at-workspace-level)
- [vsCode java.test.config vmArgs not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60305138/vscode-java-test-config-vmargs-not-working)
- Thanks to your mention, there is an article with a lot of details to configure a `launch request` with a `preLaunchTask` task configuration at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-debug/blob/388c842bcc854a9e2f7f1e8fc5aa9520cb7fecf6/Configuration.md#attach-to-a-debuggee

If it helps, one of the SO questions, and a comment here, has a link to the VSCode configuration reference, https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging#_attach . There you can see the `attach request` options.

My understanding of the `attach` vs `launch` is that

- `launch` runs your App, and then automatically attaches a debugger to it.
- `attach` is used only in cases where you have an already running JVM, lets say on some remote server, and you want to debug it.

How are you running starting your JVM? My guess would be that if you are starting the JVM from terminal, then put the `server=y` option there. If you want the VSCode to run the JVM, which I assume is the case, then the `launch request` is what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I though if I change `server=n` to `server=y` that would solve the error `ERROR: transport error 202: recv error: Connection reset by peer`. I managed to create an attach request with `server=y` but the error would be thrown after a couple of minutes even after debugging is active as successful. Can you help find out why this error is thrown during the debugging session?

Comment: @tarekahf oof, I am like happy to help, but we would need to find a better chat option :D Does it work the first couple of minutes though? Also, I am no Java expert so I am not sure I will be of huge help, just saying.

Comment: That's awesome! I am searching now and I have doubt that it's the application causing this error. I will find a multi-module sample maven simple project and try to debug and see if I will get this error.

Comment: I marked this as an answer, but I will edit it later to add more details. Basically, it is only possible to change debug arguments with the `attach request`.

Comment: @tarekahf Really? AFAIK according to the docs, the `attach` config has only "location" options ie. where to connect, and everything else seems to be done using the `launch` config. Although I might be just misunderstanding your question.

Comment: Yes, the attach request depends on a task to be launched before the attach. The task will invoke the command line to launch Java.exe with the custom debug arguments. You can rip off the java.exe command from the launch request shown the integrated terminal and create the shell task accordingly. I think one of the docs you mentioned explained this in details. I can't edit the answer due to some limitation now with the site.

Comment: This is the article with a lot of details to configure a `launch request` with a `preLaunchTask` task configuration: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-debug/blob/main/Configuration.md#attach-to-a-debuggee. If you can edit the answer and provide such details, that would be great.

Comment: @tarekahf thank you! I had no idea about that repository. I have added it into the text.