# How to set java vmargs in vscode at workspace level

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Is there a way I can set java VM arguments at workspace level? That is, not having to have it in each launch configuration in the `launch.json`. A specific argument I want to be used whenever a launch is triggered for the current workspace in vscode. I also don't want it to be global to all Java projects opened in vscode, just the current workspace.

I tried adding this in `.vscode/settings.json`, but it doesn't seem to use it.

```
{
  "java.jdt.ls.vmargs": "-javaagent:/Users/me/my-agent.jar"
}
```

Any suggestions? Ways to achieve this?

Comment: Related vscode repo link: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/97363 where the same question is raised

Answer (score 6):

You should use `vmArgs` option in the `.vscode/launch.json` file, create an entry for java launcher configuration as below -

```
    {
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [

            {
                "type": "java",
                "name": "Debug (Launch) with Arguments Prompt",
                "request": "launch",
                "mainClass": "com.myapp.Main",
                "args": "${command:SpecifyProgramArgs}",
                "vmArgs" : "${command:SpecifyVMArgs}"
            }
        ]
        }
```

You can get the list of other options here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging#_launch.

Comment: This works fine. However, my requirement is different. What if I have multiple launch configurations and I want a certain vmArg to be in all of them? With the above as far as I know I will have to add the vmArg to all of them. What I am looking for is a way to add it at one levvel above so the arg is automatically added to all of the different launch options

Comment: It's impossible. You only can add it one by one.

Comment: I tried to add the argument for `agentlib` with `server=y` and it didn't override the default hard-coded one. It added a duplicate. I am afraid this option won't work. Can you help?

Answer (score 4):

You should add vmArms at workspace level in setting.json file of VSCode

Open user setting: ctrl + shift + p

from popup then you can search "Open User Setting (JSON)"

Add this line below into your user setting json file

```json
"java.debug.settings.vmArgs": "-Dappname=LocalTest ..."
```

press F5 (default) to run single java file or you can right click at the current file and choose "Run java"

Comment: This correctly answers the original question. Ignore the old comment above that says it's impossible!